# Powershell foreach behavior changes in ISE vs. CLI

Tags: powershell, powercli

In Powershell ISE, the first condition is met. When running this same exact script in CLI, it skips the if statement despite it's condition being the same. The CLI simply outputs the ending 'else' statement. It doesn't even seem to evaluate the first 2 statements. Any ideas?

```
foreach ($vm in (Get-VM -Name $vm)) {
    if($vm.ExtensionData.Runtime.PowerState -eq "poweredOn") {
        Shutdown-VMGuest -VM $vm -Confirm:$false
        while ($vm.ExtensionData.Runtime.PowerState -eq "poweredOn" -and ($x++ -lt 60))
        {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            $vm.ExtensionData.UpdateViewData("Runtime.PowerState")
            Write-Output "Waiting for $vm to shutdown gracefully. Took $x`s."
            if ($x -gt 5) {
                Write-Output "Forcefully powering off VM $vm"
                Stop-VM $vm -Confirm:$false
            }
        }
    }
    elseif($vm.ExtensionData.Runtime.PowerState -eq "poweredOff") {
        $DateTime = "$date"+"_autosnap"
        New-Snapshot -VM $vm -Name ("$date"+"_autosnap")
        Start-VM -VM $vm
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Snapshot failed. Machine is not shutdown."
    }
    Write-Host "Cleaning up previous snapshots for $vm"
    Get-Snapshot -VM $vm | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "$retention"+"_autosnap"} | Remove-Snapshot
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your session state is bad.  The full story isn't being told here which is why you don't use the ISE to test things.

Comment: The ISE is a famous source of bugs. I would avoid using it for running scripts, just use for development.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at changing your `$vm` variable usage, this could be confusing for the terminal and ISE.

Perhaps changing the variable used in the Name parameter to be `$vmname` instead. Have it look something like the following:

```
foreach ($vm in (Get-VM -Name $vmname)) {
```